How to remove accounts from Accounts > Email and Accounts?

I simply want to remove the second account. But there is no option to do so.
There is a button that say manage but I don't want to manage. I want to remove.
According to this
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-or-remove-accounts-on-your-pc-104dc19f-6430-4b49-6a2b-e4dbd1dcdf32#:~:text=from%20your%20PC%3A-,Select%20Start%20%3E%20Settings%20%3E%20Accounts%20%3E%20Email%20%26%20accounts%20.,Yes%20to%20confirm%20your%20actions
The way to do so is

To remove an account used by apps from your PC:
Select Start  > Settings  > Accounts  > Email & accounts .
Select the account you wish to remove, then select Remove.
Select Yes to confirm your actions.

That doesn't work. There is NO remove option. Only manage

Have you tried remove it from the "Other user" tabs instead of the Email & account, other user have more option for account
